# How to get result of the previous action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, console, irb

Hi Inside rails console you can get the result of the previous operation with `_` Is there any way to do such a thing inside ruby program?

Comment: What would be the point of such thing? Why you don't simply assign it to a variable?

Comment: I'm just wondering if it's possible

Comment: No, nothing like this exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

everything in Ruby is an object, so think about it, if any returned object is not assigned a reference then it will be marked for garbage collection, so no there is no way other than to assign a returned object to a variable!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with irb (and programs that improve on irb) - it's not specific to Rails. But apart from that, I'm not aware of being able to do what you want.